# Swagger UI does not show file upload option (and not only that) in OpenAPI 3.0.3 Request Body info

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I was trying to add a file upload option for a POST request in Swagger UI by following the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/).

The problem is this:

[image]

As you can see, Swagger UI does not render anything, neither for textual inputs nor for file inputs.
I tried to search on SO other answers about this but nothing.

This is the request body that I defined for the `requestBody` parameter of the path:

````yaml
CreateTicketMessagePayload:
      description: |-
        Request multipart body required to proceed in the ticket message creation processes.
        
        **Object part**:
        ```
        {
          "message": "Textual content of the message",
          "private": "Flag that indicates the message is visible just for technicians"
        }
        ```
        **File part**:
        "attachment": Message attachment file.
      content:
        multipart/form-data:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
                example: This is a message
              private:
                type: boolean
                example: false
              attachment:
                type: string
                format: binary
````

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of `multipart/form-data` requests, Swagger UI shows the inputs after you click "Try it out".

There's an existing enhancement request to display the inputs by default:
[Display static documentation information for multipart properties in OpenAPI 3.0 files](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5169)

Comment: Thank you, the missing preview misled me.

Comment: I click the try it out and it only shows plain json. There is no form displaying anything. I’m using java 11 and Jersey multipart feature.